# How do you repeat an ajax call and be able to cancel it if needed in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have 3 ajax calls that need to be run serially.  My issue is how do I do this with $interval.  Is there another way to accomplish this?

I have these calls.

```
var server1 = getDataFromServer1()
var server2 = getDataFromServer2UsingServer1Data(server1);
var server3 = getDataFromServer3UsingServer2Data(server2);
```

However I want to repeat them but be able to cancel them if I get a certain value.  Won't $interval run getDataFromServer1() before I get data from getDataFromServer3UsingServer2Data since it won't wait.  Whats the best way to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: do you want to call `getDataFromServer2UsingServer1Data()` only after returning data from `getDataFromServer1`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is correct approach or not but you can try something like this:

```
function getDataFromServer() {
  getDataFromServer1().then(function(res1) {

    if (value === YOU_CERTAIN_VALUE) {
      //do what you want
      return
    }
    getDataFromServer2UsingServer1Data(server1).then(function(res2) {

      if (value === YOU_CERTAIN_VALUE) {
        //do what you want
        return
      }

      getDataFromServer3UsingServer2Data(server2).then(function(res3) {
        if (value === YOU_CERTAIN_VALUE) {
          //do what you want
          return;
        }
        //calling the function again.
        getDataFromServer();
      });
    });
  });

}
```

Comment: Chaining promises is the way to go when there is dependency between calls. Good example

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `promise`.

You should return a promise from each of your server call like below,

```
function getDataFromServer1(){
    return $http.get('your_url', {options});
}
```

Here you are return the result from the `$http`. `$http` will return a promise so that you can handle this promise while calling this function.

Now you can achieve your requirement like this,

```
getDataFromServer1().then(function(response){
    if(response.data == someValue){
         // if you condition satisfied then call next server call
         getDataFromServer2UsingServer1Data().then(function(response){
               if(some_condition){
                    getDataFromServer3UsingServer2Data().then(function(response)        {
                    });
               }
         });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Chaining promises is the better way to handle errors and elegant when there is such dependencies.

```
function getDataFromServer1() {
    return $http
        .get('/some/url/in/server1')
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.server1Data = response.data; // If this data is needed in scope
            return response.data;
        });
}

function getDataFromServer2WithServer1Data(server1Data) {
    if(server1Data.condition === 'not met') {
        return $q.reject('server1 condition not met');
    }

    return $http
        .get('/some/url/in/server2')
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.server2Data = response.data; // If this data is needed in scope
            if(server2Data.condition === 'not met') {
                throw 'server2 condition not met'; // other way to abort the chain, it reaches the final catch block
            }

            return response.data;
        });
}

function getDataFromServer3WithServer2Data(server2Data) {

    return $http
        .get('/some/url/in/server3')
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.server3Data = response.data; // If this data is needed in scope
            return response.data;
        });
}

getDataFromServer1()
    .then(getDataFromServer2WithServer1Data)
    .then(getDataFromServer3WithServer2Data)
    .catch(function(rejectReason){
        console.log('error occured', rejectReason);
    });
```

This [blog](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/) explains more about this scenario, would recommend to go through it.

Comment: Can also throw error inside `then()` instead of using `$q.reject()`

Comment: @charlietfl, i have updated the answer, with an example that throws error.